# How to get data from one table and then compare it with other table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**I have "Products table" with following fields**
PID int,
product_name varchar(),
product_price int

**"Cart table" with following fields**
cart_ID
user_id
PID

**So I want to display cart items of logged in user**
For example if user_ID=100 is logged in , then only his cart items should be displayed to him, with all the product details.
**Am using asp.net with entity framework**

```
public ActionResult Cart()
{
    Products pro = new Products();
    Cart cart =new Cart();

    var productID = db.cartDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == cart.productId && cart.user_id == session["user_ID"]);
    return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => pid.productId == productID));
}
```

Now problem arises, `ProductID` being `var` type I cannot compare it with `pid => pid.productid`.
What I want to do is first get all the `product_id`'s of user from `cart` table by comparing `uid_id` (Logged in user) with `user_id` in `cart` table, then displaying product details of those `product_id`'s from `product` Table. So obviously I need to store multiple `product_id`'s,so that i can populate their data on the cart page.

Comment: You define Products and Cart and never use. All you need to do is define a product list on your CartViewModel fill that with the Products in the Cart and return the CartViewModel to the View. I presume db is your context this should not be left open either.

Comment: Okay ,doing so also need productIds ,as there are more than one products in the users Cart, so problem remains the same.

Comment: All you need to do is define a product LIST on your viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ expression `db.cartDetails.Where(pid=>pid.productId==cart.productId && cart.user_id==session["user_ID"])` would return a collection of `cartDetails` and not the `productId`. You must use `select` to fetch the columns you need, something like this

```
var productIDs = db.cartDetails
                   .Where(pid => pid.productId == cart.productId && cart.user_id == session["user_ID"])
                   .Select(cd => cd.productId)
                   .ToList();
```

This would return you a `List` of `productIds`. (If you wish to get only one productId, you could use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` depending on your scenario like `db.cartDetails.SingleOrDefault(pid => ...).productId`).

Also note that you could have used `int` type for `productId` instead of using `var` if you were expecting an integer. Now you are getting a collection type `IQueryable<cardDetails>` being assigned to `productId`.

Next you cannot use an equality operator for the returned `List` anymore, you should check if this list contains the `productId` from `productDetails`, something like this:

```
return View(db.productsDetails.Where(pid => productIDs.Contains(pid.productId)));
```

Couldn't test this code, but the basic idea is here.

One last thing, consider using a join between the two tables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: i tried your following code<br/>

List<int> productIDs=new List<int>();
`productIDs = db.cartDetails
                   .Where(pid => pid.productId == cart.productId && cart.user_id == session["user_ID"])
                   .Select(cd => cd.productId)
                   .ToList();`
How to store list  of productIds in this list ?

Comment: If productId in db.cartDetails is an int, the code above would save the productIds in your variable productIDs.

Comment: If your are you getting an error, could you share it?

Comment: I tried that but the list is empty ,although I have data have in database but still productIDs is empty .?

Comment: Why don't you remove the .Where(...) clause to see if productIds are fetched when you just do this: db.cartDetails.Select(cd => cd.productId).ToList() ??? If it works, and it does not work with Where, then there is problem in your Where clause?

Comment: yes , all product id's re getting stored in the list after removing the where clause, now how to compare each productIDs with their corresponding PIDs in the product table.?

Answer (score 0):

**Did this and now my cart is working fine**

```
        public ActionResult Cart()

        List<int> productIDs = new List<int>();
        productIDs = db.cartDetails.Where(ch => ch.userId ==12).Select(cd => cd.productId).ToList() ;
        List<Products> pDetails = new List<Products>();
        for(int i=0;i<productIDs.Count;i++)
        {
           pDetails.Add(db.productsDetails.Find(productIDs[i]));
        }
             return View(pDetails);
```

Comment: It's the same as the answer above, in fact db.ProductDetails.Where() was more efficient than calling db.ProductDetails.Find() in a for loop. The actual problem lied in your Where clause, anyways you didn't even have the courtesy to vote up the answer that led you the solution. This discourages people from helping others.